# autorunscript metasploit

Tags: metasploit, powershell

I'm trying to run the following autoscript

```
    use exploit/multi/handler
    set payload …
    set lhost
    set lport

    set AutoRunScript multi_console_command -r /root/script.rc
    set exitonsession false
    exploit -j
    shell
    powershell command
```

it happens that when it opens a session it runs shell but after that it doesn't run the PowerShell commands

There are post modules that allow PowerShell scripts but I would like to know how to automate run PowerShell commands through a shell or other way without using metasploit modules. I want to run a resource that opens a shell and then launches a PowerShell command.

Comment: While using Metasploit or not? You want to use a shell that is not interpreter? What you're describing is simply a shell.

Comment: yes. thats right, its a simple shell inside metasploit

Comment: So, then use another shell? You don't have to use meterpreter. This is all in the documentation.

Comment: can you provide further details about what other shells or a link to the documentation that you refer to?

Comment: If you know how to use Metasploit to launch `calc.exe`, as explained in multiple tutorials, then you can run whatever you want, including PowerShell scripts or other shells.

Comment: Shell options and documentation on payloads are a google search away.

Comment: If your Powershell scripts are not running, there maybe things on the client preventing that. But that's a completely different question, and also not a security question (that's just troubleshooting and PowerShell scripting knowledge)

Comment: thank you for the calc.exe exemple I will investigate about it, about powershell running, Im testing on my pc and doing this without the autorunscript it works fine